# Does shouldComponentUpdate prevent connected children from updating

Tags: reactjs, redux

Say I have a component that renders `children` but those children can be `redux` connected or timer based updating components. The parent component does not know that. Yet, the parent component implements `shouldComponentUpdate` for performance optimizations.

```
class Container extends React.Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) { return shallowCompare(this, nextProps, nextState) } 

  render() {
     return <div>
       <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
       { children }
     </div>
  }
}
```

Lets say, `Clock` is a self updating/connected component. And in this constellation:

```
<Container title="Current Time">
  <Clock/>
</Container>
```

would `Clock` still be updated when its properties change due to `redux` state changes or an internal timeout (however it its implemented) despite its parent component `title` never changes and therefore the `componentShouldUpdate` call returns `false`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If `Clock` is receiving props from `Container`, and `Container` does not update because of `shouldComponentUpdate`, then `Clock` will not update. If it is connected to the store, then it should update because it will receive props directly.

Comment: And if clock uses a timer and local component state updates?

Comment: `shouldComponentUpdate` only blocks render changes on the level of the component with `shouldComponentUpdate`. If children are expecting updated props from the parent with `shouldComponentUpdate` and there is no update, the children will not update either. If there are state changes specifically handled by children (or props piped from `connect`), then those are separate.

Comment: I don't think this holds true anymore (RN 0.62.2). I had a `TileContainer` with multiple `Tile` children. The `TileContainer` had a `shouldComponentUpdate` that returned false. Neither the `Tile`'s render or `shouldComponentUpdate` were called until I removed it from the parent container.